# no html/jsx indentation in jsx-mode

Tags: indentation, web-mode, html

For some reason the html/jsx in my react source files always wants to indent as follows, i.e. there is almost no indentation:

```
return (
  <DateRangePicker ranges={this.state.ranges} startDate={this.state.startDate} endDate={this.state.endDate}
  onApply={this.applyEvent}>
    <Button className="selected-date-range-btn" style={{width : '250px'}}>
    <div className="pull-left">
    <Glyphicon glyph="calendar"/>
    </div>
    <div className="pull-right"><span>{label}</span></div>
    </Button>
  </DateRangePicker>
)
```

What I'd really like is something like the following:

```
<DateRangePicker ranges={this.state.ranges} startDate={this.state.startDate} endDate={this.state.endDate}
             onApply={this.applyEvent}>
    <Button className="selected-date-range-btn" style={{width : '250px'}}>
        <div className="pull-left">
            <Glyphicon glyph="calendar"/>
        </div>
        <div className="pull-right"><span>{label}</span></div>
    </Button>
</DateRangePicker>
```

This is the indentation I get when I copy the html/jsx to the scratch buffer with html-mode or web-mode enabled. As you can see, the indentation is much more readable and it works like this whether I use html-mode or web-mode.

How can I make my react source files indent the html/jsx like this?

Comment: What is the file extension of your file ?

Comment: I've tested it with the extensions .js and .jsx

Comment: with .jsx, it should be ok. Are you sure you have associated .jsx files with web-mode (as shown on http://web-mode.org) ?

Comment: the question is about jsx-mode not web mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/jsx/jsx-mode.el/issues/8) and as of now, it has not been fixed. I've decided to forego `jsx-mode` for this reason and just use `web-mode`. It has support for JSX and is better suited for mixed content files.

Since I do work in several projects that don't all have the same convention of using the `.jsx` ending for JSX files (some simply use `.js` endings), I've also implemented the following hack to set the `web-mode-content-type` to `jsx`, when it's "javascript". This has the consequence that all javascript files are considerd JSX, but hopefully this will not have any negative consequences.

```
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        ;; short circuit js mode and just do everything in jsx-mode
        (if (equal web-mode-content-type "javascript")
            (web-mode-set-content-type "jsx")
          (message "now set to: %s" web-mode-content-type))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was a huge pain point in emacs that you helped me with.

Answer (score 9):

FYI for anyone else who comes across this issue, this is because this jsx-mode project is **not made to edit Facebook's React JSX templates** but rather this **other compiled javascript language** also called [JSX](http://jsx.github.io).

That having the same name as the React templates is entirely coincidental.

This is why the first commits to [this repo](https://github.com/jsx/jsx-mode.el) were 4 years (pre-dating Facebook's JSX and React by years) and the last commit in this repo was back in 2013 (also pre-dating React).