# Emacs acting strangely with indentation

Tags: indentation, html, javascript

So I've recently come back to working with emacs again I mostly write JavaScript in particular React these days and I'm noticing some strange behaviour when trying to indent my code.

it seems the indentation will only work for the first couple of times and then everything after a certain point has to be on the same indent. For example:

```
import React from 'react';


const About = () => {
  return (
    <div className="about">
    <div className="header">

    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

You will notice that the react component above that the header div is indented to the same level as the about container. but all other indentation is fine. If I try to add any further elements in the header or anywhere else in the container the indentation remains the same too.

Here is my .emacs (apologies for the mess):

```
;; Include MELPA packages
(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
  (require 'package)
  (package-initialize)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
  )

;; KEY MODIFIERS
(global-set-key (kbd "M-3") '(lambda () (interactive) (insert "#")))
(defalias 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)

;; YASNIPPET
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

;; IDO MODE
(ido-mode 1)
(setq ido-file-extensions-order '(".js" ".json" ".scss" ".html" ".css"  ".yml"  ".rb"))
(setq ido-create-new-buffer 'always)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(setq ido-everywhere t)

;; THEME
;; (load-theme 'tsdh-dark)

;; WEB MODE
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "Hooks for Web mode."
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 2)
)

(add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'my-web-mode-hook)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.scss\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.css\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jsx\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.json\\'" . json-mode))


;; No more backup files
(setq make-backup-files nil)

;; FLYCHECK
(require 'flycheck)

;; turn on flychecking globally
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)

;; disable jshint since we prefer eslint checking
(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers
  (append flycheck-disabled-checkers
    '(javascript-jshint)))

;; use eslint with web-mode for jsx files
(flycheck-add-mode 'javascript-eslint 'web-mode)

;; customize flycheck temp file prefix
(setq-default flycheck-temp-prefix ".flycheck")

;; disable json-jsonlist checking for json files
(setq-default flycheck-disabled-checkers
  (append flycheck-disabled-checkers
    '(json-jsonlist)))

;; https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell
;; only need exec-path-from-shell on OSX
;; this hopefully sets up path and other vars better
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages
   '(yasnippet exec-path-from-shell web-mode flycheck darkmine-theme json-mode js3-mode)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

I've been banging my head agasint this problem for most of the morning, so I thought it was time to ask on here. Any help towards getting my indentation working correctly would be a huge help!

TIA

Comment: That's some freakish blending of JS and HTML you have there.  You seem to be using `web-mode` -- does it even support this style of code?  Perhaps https://patrickskiba.com/emacs/2019/09/07/emacs-for-react-dev.html helps?

Comment: Tbh that’s a pretty standard format for a React component @phils

Answer (score 3):

With `web-mode`, make sure your treating your code as React, not JavaScript.

Using your init file, and saving your example code to a file with a `.js` extension, I get the behavior you describe. Saving your example code to a `.jsx` file, the html is syntax highlighted and indented properly.

To specify ReactJS vs JavaScript you could mess with `web-mode-content-type` and/or `web-mode-set-content-type` a la this emacs.SE answer [no html/jsx indentation in jsx-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20016/no-html-jsx-indentation-in-jsx-mode/20055#20055) or expand what files get what content type a la this emacs.SE answer [Formatting jsx in js files with web-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27715/formatting-jsx-in-js-files-with-web-mode/27747#27747). You can also settings on a per-project basis with [directory local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html).

Comment: So the only way to get web-mode to respect React code is to use the .jsx file extension? It’s a small change I guess, but could cause problems on projects where most of the codebase has already been written like this.

Comment: No, its just the test I did. See my update.

Comment: Interesting, I never thought to try swapping out the file extension, I guess I’ve got so used to using .js instead or .jsx. At least that gives me something more to go on, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solved: After some digging it turns out the solution is actually really simple you just need to tell web mode to act the same for.js and .jsx files by adding this line into your emacs config:

```
(setq web-mode-content-types-alist '(("jsx" . "\\.js[x]?\\'")))
```